# Camera feed slow to load with AVCaptureSession on iOS - How can I speed it up?

Tags: ios, camera, photo, avcapturesession

Right now I'm trying to allow users to take pictures in my app without using UIImagePickerController. I'm using AVCaptureSession and all the related classes to load a camera feed as a sublayer on a full-screen view I have on one of my view controllers. The code works but unfortunately the camera is very slow to load. Usually takes 2-3 seconds. Here is my code:

```
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

if ([session canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh])
    //Check size based configs are supported before setting them
    [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];

[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720];

CALayer *viewLayer = self.liveCameraFeed.layer;
//NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = viewLayer.bounds;
[viewLayer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

AVCaptureDevice *device;

if(isFront)
{
    device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
}
else
{
    device = [self frontCamera];
}

AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVCaptureDeviceInput * audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:nil];
[session addInput:audioInput];

NSError *error = nil;
input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    //NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}

[session addInput:input];
[session startRunning];

stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
[session addOutput:stillImageOutput];
```

Is there any way to speed it up? I've already tried loading it on another thread using Grand Central Dispatch and NSThread and though that stopped the app from freezing it made the loading of the camera take even longer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I need to wait for `session` to start running

```
dispatch_async(queue) {
  self.session.startRunning()

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.delegate?.cameraManDidStart(self)

    let layer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In most tutorials on the web `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is attached to the session before startRunning() is called, but in fact preview appears much faster if you attach it asynchronously after the session was started!

Comment: For whatever reason, attaching the session to the preview layer AFTER the session has started, delays the initial `captureOutput...` call, so beware!

Answer (score 13):

Waiting for **AVCaptureSession**'s `startRunning` function was my solution too. You can run `startRunning` in global async and then in main thread you can add your **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer**.

**Swift 4** sample

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    self.captureSession.startRunning()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can load the AVCaptureSession at the time of `viewWillAppear`. It works for me. When I switch to the view with the `AVCaptureSession` from other view, then I see the camera running immediately.

Comment: Actually this helped in my case. I can see 2-3 seconds improvement by placing this peace of code: `[viewLayer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];` from `viewDidAppear` to `viewWillAppear`. Have no idea why is this so faster, but you can test for yourself and confirm this...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested the solution I came up with was preloading the camera on a different thread and keeping it open.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested! So you keep the AVCaptureSession (with input(s)) around all the time? What is the performance impact of this? Thanks.

Comment: It's very heavy. But I haven't found a better solution. The capture session remains open but the feed layer is added and removed from my camera view repeatedly. So, if the user tries to open the camera, the capture session feed sublayer is added to my camera view and when the user backs out of the camera the feed sublayer is removed.

Comment: This was awhile ago so I need to check the code to remember exactly what I did but if I remember correctly my solution was to load the camera on a different thread and keep it open but only show the sublayer when the user wants to use the camera. Otherwise, still keep the camera open in the background but remove the sublayer.

Comment: Edit: It's a modified version of the above.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all the above methods but it was not as good as Instagram or Facebook, So I loaded the AVCaptureDevice, AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, AVCaptureSession in the Parent Screen and passed it as parameter to the Child Screen. It was loading very rapidly.